# Updating Webpage from Within Thread

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, multithreading, twitter-bootstrap

I have a webpage that runs a lengthy procedure, it's all working apart from displaying the progress on the page.

I have the following progress bar (Bootstrap):

```
<div class="col-md-8">
  <label for="product-feed-progress">Progress</label>
    <div class="progress">
     <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" runat="server" id="prgProdFeed" style="min-width: 0em; width: 0%;">
                                    0%
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

During the thread, I have the following snippet that adjusts the width property of prgProdFeed:

```
prgProdFeed.Attributes.Add("style", "width:" & ((p_objFeedInfo.Progress / p_objFeedInfo.Total) * 100).ToString() + "%")
```

I have also tried:

```
prgProdFeed.Style.Item("width") = ((p_objFeedInfo.Progress / p_objFeedInfo.Total) * 100).ToString() + "%"
```

They both change the width property of the bar which currently sits in an update panel (updated on the tick of a timer).

How come my progress bar is not updating on the page? I can see using the inspector that the update panel is refreshing, and in the debugger it's showing the width being correct - just nothing changes visually.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Suppose you have thousand concurrent users which opens your page. Do you have single "long-runnnig" thread for them all, or one per each? Then, how your long-running thread (or threads) understands which one of these thousand users came with UpdatePanel request every time? In other words, how do you synchronize long-running thread with particular http request?

Comment: Hmm, okay I see what you mean. I'll continue looking at other ways to show  progress to the user.

Comment: @MrDKOz you could look into using SignalR or web sockets.

Comment: Lanorkin Asp.Net is build to handle these kinds of situations.That is not the problem. However as @NKosi suggests there are far more efficient methods for something like this. Even creating a generic handler to get progress as a JSON object would be far better than using the Update Panel. In general the Update Panel is awesome when it works but went it doesn't it will have you ripping your hair out. I've posted an answer with working code below.

Answer (score 4):

Working code is below.

I would suggest you make sure your update panel is actually being refreshed. with my code you can do a hard updated of the web page (eg F5) and you'll see updated progress. Initially, my code to refresh the update panel wasn't triggering. I was using Query to trigger a click on the refresh linkbutton in the update panel but I needed to change the code to call the __doPostBack.

Another thing I would would check in your code is that `p_objFeedInfo.Progress` is a double and `p_objFeedInfo.Total` is a double. You could be having an issue where one is an int and the double result from (`p_objFeedInfo.Progress / p_objFeedInfo.Total`) being less than 1 is converted as in integer rounded down to 0 before being multiplied by 100.

Besides that I am combining the width attribute into a string and also setting prgProdFeed.InnerText to that string so I don't need worry about inspecting an element to see if the width is changing. I am also setting the width use Style("Width"):

```
Dim progressAttribute As String = progress & "%"
Me.prgProdFeed.Style("Width") = progressAttribute
Me.prgProdFeed.InnerText = progressAttribute
```

To simulate your long running thread I created a feed class that takes `Total` as a constructor. It returns progress as double based on the number of seconds that have passed since the class was created.

```vb
Public Class ProgressBar
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Public Class FeedInfo
        Public ReadOnly Property Progress As Double
            Get
                Return Math.Min(Now.Subtract(Created).TotalSeconds, Total)
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Total As Double
        Public Created As DateTime
        Public Sub New(Total)
            Me.Total = Total
            Created = Now
        End Sub
    End Class
    Private Property info As FeedInfo
        Get
            If (Not Session("info") Is Nothing) Then
                Return Session("info")
            End If
            Return Nothing
        End Get
        Set(value As FeedInfo)
            Session("info") = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim progress As Integer = 0
        If (Not info Is Nothing) Then
            Dim tracker As FeedInfo = info
            Dim trackerProgress As Double = tracker.Progress
            Dim trackerTotal As Double = tracker.Total
            progress = ((trackerProgress / trackerTotal) * 100)
        End If
        Dim progressAttribute As String = progress & "%"
        Me.prgProdFeed.Style("Width") = progressAttribute
        Me.prgProdFeed.InnerText = progressAttribute

    End Sub

    Private Sub runProc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles runProc.Click
        info = New FeedInfo(600)
    End Sub
End Class
```

```html
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="ProgressBar.aspx.vb" Inherits="EFWCFVB.ProgressBar" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Long Running Task Progress Bar</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var timerId = 0;
        function trackProgress() {
            if (timerId && timerId != 0)
                return;
            timerId = window.setInterval(refreshProgress, 2000);
        }
        function refreshProgress() {
            if ($('.progress-bar').html() == "100%") {
                window.clearInterval(timerId); return;
            }
            //  $('#btnRefresh').click(); does not work
            // var href = $('#btnRefresh').attr("href").split[0]; //"javascript:__doPostBack('btnRefresh','')"
            __doPostBack('btnRefresh', '');

        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            trackProgress();
            $('#runProc').click(function () { trackProgress();})
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <h2>Long Running Task Progress Bar</h2>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-8">

                        <label for="product-feed-progress">Progress</label>
                        <div class="progress">
                            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" runat="server" id="prgProdFeed" style="min-width: 0em; width: 0%;">
                                0%
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <asp:Button ID="runProc" runat="server" Text="Run" />
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnRefresh" runat="server" Text="Refresh Panel">

                        </asp:LinkButton>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>

        </asp:UpdatePanel>


    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

"width" is not the right property for a bargraph object. Usually, width denotes the width of the entire object.

You need to  look for a "**value**" property instead of "width"

Comment: I did: I told "value". But thanks for the downvote anyway.

Comment: *Have you tried to look for a "value" instead of "width" ?*. Don't assume that who comments dv, instead try to improve your answer

Comment: Be sure that as soon as I will have the right to comment, I wil comment instead of trying to suggest things to be taken in account. I thought that my answer could be helpful, though.