# SignalR functions not called until Code block finished

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I am using SignalR to start a process and provide a live progress bar on its status. I have SignalR working ok and client button calls the archive function in the hub:

```
public class ProgressHub : Hub
{    
    private static IHubContext hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ProgressHub>();

    public void archive()
    {
        ArchiveFunctions.ArchiveData();
    }

    public static void SendArchiveProgress(int width, string value)
    {
        hubContext.Clients.All.updateArchiveProgress(width, value);
    }
}
```

This is just calling a static void on a class looping through database rows and all this code is working as well.  Part of this code works out how many rows it has done so far and calls SignalR function to inform the user after each row:

```
public class ArchiveFunctions {
    public static void ArchiveData() {
        // gets data etc
        // loops records, below line occurs for each record
        ProgressHub.SendArchiveProgress(progressaspercentage, value);
    }
}
```

All the code appears to be working however the SendArchiveProgress doesn't update the client until AFTER the void has finished running and then all the messages come at once.  If I put a breakpoint in the void then it does get the message as it hits it.  I attempted to use async/await but I have little knowledge of using it and although I got no errors it just didn't seem to work.

If I am missing something obvious please say so I can delete question than downvote without providing a reason, its very frustrating.

JS code as requested:

```
$(function () {
    var chat = $.connection.progressHub;

    chat.client.updateArchiveProgress = function (width, value) {
        $('.progress-bar').css('width', width + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', width);
        $("#lblProgress").text(value);
    };

    // Start the connection.
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        $('#btnStart').click(function () {
                $('.progress-bar').css('width', '0%').attr('aria-valuenow', '0');
                $("#lblProgress").text("Starting process...");
                $("#modProgress").modal();
                chat.server.archive();                
        });
    });
});
```

UPDATE: I'm very embarrassed to admit that the simple cause was that the code block in ArchiveData() ran so quickly it just appeared to send all at the end and a slight delay at signalr running the void helped give that impression.  So in actual fact all this code works very well and I tested it by adding some simple loop code to add some extra seconds between each record to make it run longer.  Not sure if I should delete the question as no answers or leave to help others??

Comment: Can you post remaining code which includes call to the `SendArchiveProgress`

Comment: Have you seen this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44823859/updating-webpage-from-within-thread

Comment: I'm not sure which code you want as the rest is irrelevant to my issue. The ArchiveData() is just a static void on a class and loops database records and for each one calls the line as above

Comment: @PaulF Thanks but I'd like to stick to the SignalR method if possible

Comment: Please, update your question with the client side code that you have.

Comment: One lesson, I learnt early on was, don't build for SignalR, build your system and add in SignalR as an extension. Seems most fitting for Server Broadcast: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-signalr

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez Added as requested

Comment: regarding your update.. you're free to answer your own question with that information. It could provide useful to future visitors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my update to this question I felt I should answer the question myself to leave the code that is working well available for other people as it also shows how to call signalr functions from Controllers or other classes as well.